# Signature for Generic Mutable Vector function

Tags: haskell, mutable, higher-rank-types

I'm trying to write a generic vector function that takes an immutable vector and returns an immutable vector, but operates on a (temporary) mutable vector. A simple example that demonstrates my problem is:

```
import Data.Vector.Generic as V
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as M

test :: (Vector v r) => v r -> v r
test v = runST $ do
  x <- V.thaw v
  -- modify the mutable vector x, code elided
  let s = V.sum x
  M.write x 0 s
  -- continue to modify the mutable vector x, code elided
  V.unsafeFreeze x
```

This function does not compile because GHC cannot deduce `(Vector (Mutable v s) r)`. I realize this is a problem, but due to the higher-rank type of `runST`,

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

I can't just add this constraint to `test`, nor could I figure out how to appropriately use explicit forall'd variables. How can I make `test` compile?

Comment: If you mean that `V.sum` will be replaced by a monadic function which operates on a mutable vector then you should bind its result using the bind operator and not using `let`. Otherwise, if your aim is to just use `V.sum` for immutable vectors then you can just replace `V.sum x` with `V.sum v` since `x` was not modified. However, if `x` was modified then you have to freeze it to use `V.sum`.

Comment: I don't have a monadic version of `sum`, unfortunately. Perhaps there is one? I also can't use `v` because I modify the (thawed) version of v before calling sum. I *could* refreeze x first, but that's what I'm tring to avoid.

Comment: Currently, the only solution I can think of is to `unsafeFreeze` it or implement the mutable version yourself. I've opened a ticket about the missing list-like functions in the mutable vector modules this morning.

Comment: Is it okay to do `y<-V.unsafeFreeze x; let s= V.sum y; z<-V.unsafeThaw y; ...continue operating on the mutable vector z`? Basically: can I do two consecutive unsafe operations and still have access to my vector? Could I use the old handle x (since nothing was modified), or would be forced to use the new handle z?

Comment: Best to assume nothing though, right? A new handle in constant time shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19681/discussion-between-eric-and-is7s)